# Need nested parenthesis for this regex

Tags: java, regex, shell

I have got dataset like this with three columns

> Col1, Col2, Col2
>
> aaa,Arizona   DL USTATES,12
>
> bbb,Idaho   DL USTATES,35
>
> ccc,Idaho   DL USTATES,28
>
> ddd,Wisconsin   DL USTATES,11
>
> eeee,Wisconsin   DL USTATES,35

What I want to do is that I want to extract the first word of the second column(what is a state name) and put it in the first column.

> Expected Output:
>
> Arizona,Arizona randam USTATES,12
>
> Idaho,Idaho randam USTATES,35
>
> Idaho,Idaho randam USTATES,28
>
> Wisconsin,Wisconsin random USTATES,11

The regex that I have is

> ^[^,]+,([^ ]+) [^\n]+$

With my () I can extract the state name, but How do get the output? What I want is nested parenthesis, something like this

> ^[^,]+,(([^ ]+) [^\n]+)$

and then the output will be
\1,\2

I should point out that I want to do it using regex replace only.

Edit:

I have solved it by using regex to get all of the state names in a column and then merged it, but I want to know if there are any advanced regex which can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex with nested parentheses works fine; you just need to use `String`'s `replaceFirst` method and note that Java uses `$` for group references.  Also note that the groups are enumerated in the order they occur in the regex, so the outer group is `$1` because it starts first:

```
String line = "aaa,Arizona DL USTATES,12";
String result = line.replaceFirst("^[^,]+,(([^ ]+) [^\n]+)$", "$2, $1");
// result is "Arizona, Arizona DL USTATES,12"
```

Comment: Is this possible in shell as well?

Comment: It should be, but the only way of doing it in a shell script I'm familiar with is using a command like `awk`, `sed`, or `perl`, and the group reference syntax will vary a little depending on the command.

Comment: You could do it in a shell by playing tricks with IFS and adding some logic to handle state names with spaces. It's not a regex solution though.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "aaa,Arizona DL USTATES,12";

String st = s.split(",")[1].split(" ")[0];
s = s.replaceFirst("\\w+\\,", st + ",");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is not what I am looking for, what I want to know is that if the parenthesis can be nested?